# What mean $\int \mathcal D(n(x)) \delta \left(n(x)-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N \delta (x-x_i)\right)$?

Tags: probability-theory, mathematical-physics

In formula (4.5) page 27 of [this document](https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.07903), what mean
$$\int \mathcal D(n(x)) \delta \left(n(x)-\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N \delta (x-x_i)\right),$$
where the integral run over all possible normalized, non negative smooth function $n(x)$, and $\delta $ is the $\delta $ distribution. Could someone explain what is this integral, how it work and why this integral is $1$ ?

Comment: Please do not force people to download the whole PDF, simply to be able to know the title and authors and abstract of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a path integral. Actually the result should be $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N \delta (x-x_i)$. Then when you integrate over $x$ one more time it is $=1$.

Look into distributions to get a explanation for the $\delta()$. The one appearing in your integral is a sort of infinite dimensional delta distribution.

Comment: I in fact have more difficultie to understand $\mathcal D(n(x))$ that the $\delta $.

Comment: you can approximate it by discretizing n(x) into K pieces with K very large. Then $\int \mathcal D(n(x))$ is a K dimensional integral.

Comment: It's not so easy to make it rigorous. Its an infinite dimensional integration.